# Character printing conflicts when using different charsets for static and dynamic content

Tags: php, html, mysqli, character-encoding

Would someone please tell me how to solve this encoding conflict?

*Note:* My files are saved as UTF-8 files.

When I use:

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
```

Webpage shows chars below as **normal** (they are hard-coded in the page):

```
çÇ, ğĞ, şŞ
```

But when the same characters come from DB (encoded with mysqli) they appear **abnormal**:

```
��, ��, ��
```

---

When I use:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-9">
<meta http-equiv="Content-language" content="tr">
```

Webpage shows chars below **abnormal** (they are hard-coded in the page):

```
ÄŸÃ¢, Ä±Ä°, ÅŸÄ±
```

But when the same characters come from DB (encoded with mysqli) they appear **normal**:

```
çÇ, ğĞ, şŞ
```

Comment: Have you checked your encoding in the db ?
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: Yes some of the chars encoded and some of them not, strange enough! e.g . `ö` is not encoded while `ğ` is encoded as `&#287;`.

Comment: Your answer is in there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: @Mihai -  Thanks for the link which helped me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the post as given by @Mihai above, I solved the problem with `$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');` and just kept `<meta charset="utf-8">`. That's it!